# Can the moderators convert a comment into an answer?

Tags: support, feature-request, moderators, comments, moderation

I know that moderators can take an answer that should be a comment, and turn it into a comment (attributed to same poster).

Can moderators do the reverse (turn comment into an answer posted by same user) when a comment that really stands out as a decent answer is posted? E.g. [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39553/976)

Please note that the question is merely a technical **"can"**, e.g. I don't care about policy, "should", or whether it's a good/bad idea angles - although I suspect everyone's consensus would be on "bad idea". Merely want to know if the software on SE allows this.

Comment: [No](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77110/way-to-convert-a-comment-to-an-answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, moderators cannot create a full post on behalf of a user, even from a comment they posted. All we can do is what you already did, encourage them to post it as a full answer themselves.